# Access queries are missing when I establish a connection from Excel using "Get Data"

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, database-connection

Let's say you've built up a nice database, and you want to generate a read-only Excel doc so others can view it without screwing up source data. You open Excel, go to:

**Data ribbon → Get Data → From Database → From Microsoft Access Database**.

But after you preview your database on the next window, you notice that the query you need isn't there.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking a question?

Comment: If you're going to post self-answered questions, make sure to post them on the right site. Questions about the Excel GUI are off-topic here, they should be posted on superuser.com. See the tag excerpt: _Only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files, or complex formula development_

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The "complex formula development" is actually what prompted me to post this. I had an error that took me a couple hours to troubleshoot. Turns out, Access/Excel need very specific formulae to communicate with each other, which is why I listed issue# 3. The first two are effectively easy troubleshooting steps up to verifying the formulae.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely, there are three things that could be happening:

### 1) You haven't saved your databse

Most likely issue is that you created your query, but you haven't saved it or the database.

---

### 2) Existing connections may need to be refreshed

If you've already established a connection to Excel, and you've made sure the database has been saved, the next likely issue is that the connection is out of date. Even though it's "connected", the list of tables and queries may be cached and not automatically updated when prompted.

Simply go to **Data ribbon → Refresh All**

---

### 3) Your query may be using incompatible expressions

I just learned the hard way that the **nz()** function is incompatible with Excel, so when I tried to link the query, it wouldn't show up in the list. For anyone else with **nz()**, use **iif(isnull())** instead.

If your query is not showing up after saving the database or refreshing the connection, try the following:

1. In Excel, go to **Data ribbon → Get Data → *From Other Sources* → From Microsoft Query**
2. A little window will pop up. Select **MS Access Database**, and press OK
3. Another window will pop up. Navigate to your database directory, and press OK

This should show a *complete* list of your tables and queries. From there, expand the query you need. It will either connect without issue, or it will identify the unrecognized SQL expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for your third answer, i used the nz() function and was racking my brain why it was not showing in excel.